# Wireshark filtering most recent 15 minutes

Tags: filter, time, timestamp, wireshark, live

I'm capturing live traffic from a vpn interface on my router via ssh and feeding it into wireshark, is there a filter which will only show endpoints/conversations for the most recent 15 minutes?

I did find a post on using actual timestamps to create a "window" filter, but have not had any luck on finding a way to filter based on the current clock time like a variable. (https://support.solarwinds.com/SuccessCenter/s/article/Use-time-as-a-display-filter-in-Wireshark?language=en_US)

I've also found a time.time field in the filter reference but again have not had any luck in finding a way to use it https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/t/time.html

If what I am asking for is not possible with wireshark, would appreciate any/all suggestions on how I can achieve this.

Comment: You might want to consider using a ring buffer to capture and then start a new file every 15 minutes.  This can be achieved using the `-b duration:900` option.  Refer to the [Wireshark man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark.html) for more details.  Using this method, each file is smaller and faster to work with, and you don't need to filter anything because the files are already saved in 15 minute increments. 
 And if you find you need to work with multiple files, then you can always merge them later.

Comment: This sounds perfect, gonna experiment with it and will update once its done. Thank you very much @ChristopherMaynard

Comment: Tested it out @ChristopherMaynard was a good suggestion and I was hopeful, but sadly it isn't ideal in how it works because when the 15min mark comes up all early captures are out even though some of those active endpoints were still active.

Comment: I don't follow you.  When you set up the ring buffer, you can specify as many files as you want to keep using the `-b files:value` option.

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard I apologize for my poor explanation. I am mainly using the Wireshark->Statistics->Endpoints display to track endpoints. When using the ringbuffer flag as soon as wireshark starts recording a new file all the endpoints from the previous file no longer show in the refresh and only endpoint in the new file are shown.

Comment: In that case, you might want to take a look at [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) instead.  You should be able to script something that applies a filter based on the last 15 minutes using the current system time and then apply the `-z endpoints,type,filter` option.